# check if record saved in access sub macro

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an Access macro in a form that I only want to run on a blank record. How do I check to see if a record has been saved.  The Me.dirty property doesn't work for me because it checks to see if a saved record have been altered or modified.

```
Private Sub FIND_MEMBER_AfterUpdate()
    Me.FIRST_NAME = DLookup("[FIRST_NAME]", "CM_ROSTER", "[SOC_SEC_NUM] = '" & Me.SOC_SEC_NUM & "'")
    Me.MID_INIT = DLookup("[MID_INIT]", "CM_ROSTER", "[SOC_SEC_NUM] = '" & Me.SOC_SEC_NUM & "'")
    Me.LAST_NAME = DLookup("[LAST_NAME]", "CM_ROSTER", "[SOC_SEC_NUM] = '" & Me.SOC_SEC_NUM & "'")
End Sub
```

I may have a solution:

Private Sub FIND_MEMBER_AfterUpdate()

```
If Me.NewRecord = True Then


Me.FIRST_NAME = DLookup("[FIRST_NAME]", "CM_ROSTER", "[SOC_SEC_NUM] = '" & Me.SOC_SEC_NUM & "'")
Me.MID_INIT = DLookup("[MID_INIT]", "CM_ROSTER", "[SOC_SEC_NUM] = '" & Me.SOC_SEC_NUM & "'")
Me.LAST_NAME = DLookup("[LAST_NAME]", "CM_ROSTER", "[SOC_SEC_NUM] = '" & Me.SOC_SEC_NUM & "'")



Else

GoTo exit_sub

End If
```

exit_sub:

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the property you are looking for is the form's .NewRecord property, which is true until a new record is saved.